# Karma is working without specifying path to js files

Tags: karma-jasmine

I created a project using Angular CLI. It created following karma.config.js. I notice that this file doesn't contain configuration/path for the spec files but I can still use `npm test` to run karma. How come?

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

The spec file is at location `./src/app/app.component.ts`. I expected karma.conf.js to contain following line

```
files: [
'src/**/*.js'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Karma on an Angular CLI project, it ends up using `src/test.ts` file by default. You can find this in .angular-cli.json:

```
...
"test": "test.ts",
...
```

(Looks like the Angular CLI plugin at the top of the karma file is the one searching for that test.ts.)

If you look at test.ts, you'll see that it initializes a test Angular environment, and then does this:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
```

This includes all spec files within the `src` directory. By requiring those spec files, they are included in the test run. You could also remove that block and do something like:

`require('./app/search/search.component.spec.ts');`

That would only run the tests in that spec file, for instance.